# Why is my Neo4J composite index not being used with MATCH and ORDER BY?

Tags: neo4j

I have a lot of nodes of label `Person` with properties `treeId`, `firstName`, `lastName`.
I am trying to implement a performant endless scroll of all Persons with some treeId, ordered alphabetically:

```
MATCH (p:Person {treeId: "admin"}) RETURN p ORDER BY p.lastName, p.firstName SKIP 100 LIMIT 20
```

---

**Question:** What index do I need to create for this operation to run on indexes as much as possible?

I attempted to create such an index:

```
CREATE INDEX personTreeLastNameFirstName FOR (p:Person) ON (p.treeId, p.lastName, p.firstName)
```

but with this index, the first operation is `NodeByLabelScan`, so the index is not used.

Another index I tried is more helpful:

```
CREATE INDEX personTree FOR (p:Person) ON p.treeId
```

the first operation is `NodeIndexSeek` when using it, but it doesn't include the names, so every Person with the specified treeId needs to be read from the database.

What index do I need to create, or how do I need to rewrite the query for it to be more performant on large amounts of Persons with the same treeId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index :

```
CREATE INDEX personTree FOR (p:Person) ON p.treeId
```

only indexes `treeId`, hence it can only be used to sort and search on `treeIds`.

The composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX personTreeLastNameFirstName FOR (p:Person) ON (p.treeId, p.lastName, p.firstName)
```

indexes `treeId`, `lastName` and `firstName`, but the catch here is it will only be used if all the three indexed keys are present in the search clause, that's why you are getting `NodeByLabelScan`. To allow neo4j to use your composite index, you should add some search criteria for `firstName` and `lastName`. Like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WHERE p.treeId= "admin" AND p.firstName > "" AND p.lastName > "" 
RETURN p 
ORDER BY p.lastName, p.firstName 
SKIP 100 LIMIT 20
```